# How to handle errors with fault consumers where the fault consumer needs additional parameters?

Tags: masstransit

We are using MassTransit in an event sourcing a like system where we have services that are used by different clients. The requirement is to only give users feedback when something goes wrong and we were therefor thinking of using the fault consumers with FaultAddress for the clients. The clients would set the fault address on all commands they are sending and then implement fault consumers that would get a message whenever we get an exception in our services. This is working but the issue is that we need to add some extra data to the messages the services don't require in order to route the message correctly from the fault consumer. My idea was to add the parameters on the client side without having them on the contract. Let say we have an order service with an order consumer `OrderConsumer : IConsumer<IOrder>`.

We create a class on the client side with the extra parameter not needed by the order service.

```
Order : IOrder {
 string ClientId{get;set;}
}
```

I wanted to be able to use `OrderFaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<Order>>` but that is not working and I need to create `OrderFaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<IOrder>>` instead. It is easy to understand why we need to use `IOrder` when we look at the actual messages sent.

The command message:

```
 "messageType": [
    "urn:message:Order",
    "urn:message:IOrder"
  ],

  "message": {
    "ClientId": "..."
  },
```

Fault message:

```
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:MassTransit:Fault[[IOrder]]",
    "urn:message:MassTransit:Fault"
  ],
"message": {
}
```

I was hoping that the fault message would keep Order and the message sent:

```
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:MassTransit:Fault[[Order]]",
    "urn:message:MassTransit:Fault[[IOrder]]",
    "urn:message:MassTransit:Fault"
  ],
"message": {
    "ClientId": "..."
}
```

I can of course add ClientId to `IOrder` and it would work for the application. The issue with that is that the service doesn't care about ClientId and another client may need some other data like EmailAddress in order to route the error message correctly.

- What would be a good approach to handle the extra parameters with
  Mass transit?
- Should I continue with fault consumer or is that a bad
  approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fault<T>` gets `T` generic parameter based on the consumer, where the failure occurs. If the consumer implements `IConsumer<IOrder>` - the fault event will have the `Fault<IOrder>` contract.

Put the data you need in headers if you do not want to change the contract.
`Fault` and `Fault<T>` events get everything in the payload.

I'd also rather avoid using `I` prefix for message interfaces. You win nothing by doing that, but it creates confusion. These are message contracts. Interfaces are just a way of defining them.

Comment: Thank you. The header worked perfectly for what I needed. I think we have to continue with `I` even though I agree with you.